# Keras / Tensorflow incompatible shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm pretty new to tensorflow / keras and I can't find a fix to this problem. I have a training data set of ~4000 20-dimensional vectors that each describe a document. I also have those same document-vectors at a later state. I want to predict how the document-vector will be at the end from the initial state. I compared the document vectors at state 0 with their final state using cosine similarity and got about .5. The goal is to improve that with a simple model. Currently i am doing:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', input_dim=20))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='cosine_similarity', metrics [tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(input_train, y_train,
                epochs=30,
                batch_size=16,
                validation_data=(input_test,y_test),
                callbacks=[tbCallBack]
               )
```

After 30 epochs this gives me a validation cosine similarity of .66, so my guess is that this actually did improve my initial cosine similarity and produced at least some sort of value added.

Then I want to look at the predictions to see if they make any sense:

```
lol = np.asarray([0.0125064 , 0.01250269, 0.01250133, 0.01250481, 0.01250508,
   0.0125009 , 0.0125009 , 0.01250437, 0.01250131, 0.01250181,
   0.01250403, 0.0125038 , 0.01250372, 0.01250246, 0.01250183,
   0.01250226, 0.01250294, 0.76244247, 0.01250485, 0.01250205])
model.predict([lol])
#model.predict(lol)
```

Both predict versions give me the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 20) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 20), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_69_input'), name='dense_69_input', description="created by layer 'dense_69_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
```

Does someone know how to solve this? Also, if someone is familiar with this kind of goal, is this the right way? Is there something I can do differently?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `np.expand_dims` to add the batch dimension to your array:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu', input_dim=20))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='cosine_similarity', metrics= [tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)])
model.summary()
input_train = tf.random.normal((5, 20))
y_train = tf.random.normal((5, 20))
history = model.fit(input_train, y_train,
                epochs=1,
                batch_size=2)

lol = np.asarray([0.0125064 , 0.01250269, 0.01250133, 0.01250481, 0.01250508,
   0.0125009 , 0.0125009 , 0.01250437, 0.01250131, 0.01250181,
   0.01250403, 0.0125038 , 0.01250372, 0.01250246, 0.01250183,
   0.01250226, 0.01250294, 0.76244247, 0.01250485, 0.01250205])
lol = np.expand_dims(lol, axis=0)
model.predict(lol)
```

```
array([[0.0727988 , 0.        , 0.3008919 , 0.00460427, 0.        ,
        0.01472487, 0.31665963, 0.11831823, 0.        , 0.05261957,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.13595472,
        0.07765757, 0.09340346, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],
      dtype=float32)
```